# Getter Error in Java

Tags: java, getter

I started java this summer and am designing a small game in my free time. The problem I have right now is with a getter.  In a `Player` class I have a getter for an integer "`speed`".

Here is the code:

```
public int getSpeed(){
    return this.speed;
}
```

This integer "`speed`" is set in a constructor:

```
public Player(int x, int y, String n, BufferedImage s, int spd) {
    super(x, y);
    this.name = n;
    this.sprite = s;
    spd = this.speed;
    this.l_x = x;
    this.l_y = y;
}
```

When I try to use the "`speed`" variable in a movement code:

```
if (w) {
    p_y -= player.getSpeed();
}
```

I get this error at runtime (thank you Martijn Courteaux):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.gameMain.update(gameMain.java:81)
```

Where line 81 is the line that the movement code appears on.

I would greatly appreciate any help that I could get as I could make everything "work" by using individual variables for everything, but it would be 10x easier and cleaner if I could know why my getter's aren't working.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I changed

> spd = this.speed;

to

> this.speed = spd;

but, I am still getting the Null Pointer Exception Error.  In fact any variable that I am trying to use from the throws the same error.

Can anyone see any major errors?
And thanks to everyone that has helped so far! I greatly appreciate it!

package main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player extends Character {

```
private String name;
private BufferedImage sprite;
private int speed, l_x, l_y;

public Player(int x, int y, String n, BufferedImage s, int spd) {
    super(x, y);
    this.name = n;
    this.sprite = s;
    speed = spd;
    this.l_x = x;
    this.l_y = y;
}

public int getSpeed(){
    return this.speed;
}

public void setSpeed(int i){
    this.speed = i;
}

public int getOriginalX(){
    return super.o_loc_x;
}

public int getOringinalY(){
    return super.o_loc_y;
}

public int getCurrentY(){
    return this.l_y;
}

public int getCurrentX(){
    return this.l_x;
}

public void setCurrentY(int i){
    i = this.l_y;
}

public void setCurrentX(int i){
    i = this.l_x;
}

public void moveUp(){
    this.l_y -= speed;
}

public void moveDown(){
    this.l_y += speed;
}

public void moveLeft(){
    this.l_x -= speed;
}

public void moveRight(){
    this.l_x += speed;
}

public void setName(String input){
    this.name = input;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void setSprite(BufferedImage m){
    this.sprite = m;
}

public BufferedImage getSprite(){
    return this.sprite;
}
```

}

EDIT: I am such an idiot. WHen I was declaring a new instance of Player, I put

> Player player =...

Instead of:

> player = ....

Comment: The compiler didn't give that error. It's thrown at runtime.

Comment: I changed the question to reflect.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: I would suggest that you don't accept an answer that isn't actually the answer.  If you have found the answer yourself post it then accept that.

Comment: DaveJohnson, if you would like to make the reply, please.  I cannot answer my own question for 6 hours since my reputation is low.

Comment: @ZjijZ I have updated my answer to reflect your discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointerException is in your gameMain class, so we need to see that to see what the problem might be.

As you have now pointed out in your question the problem was caused by your assignment to the player variable.  Instead of assigning to the instance variable you have created a new local variable and assigned to that, thus future access to the instance variable results in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
spd = this.speed;
```

With:

```
this.speed = spd;
```

Comment: I changed the code, but I am still getting errors (with all of my getters).  The IDE is Eclipse if that helps.

Comment: speed and spd are ints, how would this be the source of a NullPointerException?

Comment: Yes, if you never assign an int a value it will initially be 0

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your arguments final. In that case, you cannot assign other values (or, again, references) to the arguments by mistake. Again, you will get a clear compiler error if you mess up.

Make sure that your the fields that do not change (the values for base types and the references for all others) are set to final, and you will get a clear compiler error when you forget to set them during construction. If you have only "final" fields, your class will be immutable (see Effective Java by Joshua Bloch for reasons to use immutable classes). But the speed probably changes when you run the application, so that will not work for this particular field. I'll demo it for the name.

So that would be:

```
private final String name;
private int speed;

public Player(final String n, final int spd) {
    spd = this.speed; // cannot assign, it's final
    // whoops, another error, forgot to assign a value to the name field
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use e.g. "Clean Code" in Eclipse to automatically assign final modifiers to those variables that haven't received a second value yet, in case you get tired of typing "final" all the time.

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
`spd = this.speed;`
```

to:

```
`speed = spd;`
```

Comment: speed and spd are ints, how would this be the source of a NullPointerException?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your problem:

```
spd = this.speed;
```

You want

```
this.speed = spd;
```

In Java (and most programming languages for that matter) the variable being assigned to needs to be on the left hand side not the right.

What you were doing is assigning the existing value of speed to the local variable in the constructor.

Comment: speed and spd are ints, how would this be the source of a NullPointerException?